# VBA drops the decimal point when multiplying decimal with whole number

Tags: vba, ms-access, decimal, modulus

I have a userform that retrieves price amount from an Access table. Prices can be decimals. To compute the total prices of a line, I have to multiply it by the quantity.

A typical example is:

- `Price = 10.45`
- `Quantity = 1`

Logically, what I want is `Tot = 10.45*1 = 10.45`. But VBA gives me `1045` without the decimal point.

I have scrolled through the forum and seen some suggestions (converting to decimals, using modulus, declaring double, single, float,...) but the result does not change.

The code that I am using goes like this:

```
Me.lblPU = (rs!price - (rs!price  * (5 / 100)))
Me.lblPriceTot = (CDec(Me.lblPU) * CDec(Me.Qty))
```

The field `lblPU` is giving the correct number: `10.45`
But the field `lblPriceTot` is giving `1045` as a result.

I didn't declare any variable regarding this fields because they are actually retrieved from Access and therefore are not encoded by a user.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Difficult to see how this is happening if lblPU is really 10.45 and quantity is really 1

Comment: If you are using dot as thousands separator then normally 10.45 would mean 1045. Instead of strings work with numerics or use correct decimal separator based on regional settings.

Comment: if the regional settings used the comma then his label would display 10,45 but it displays 10.45 so the comma is probably not the issue.

Comment: Check value of Excel Options->Advanced->Use system separators.. Seems unticked.

Comment: Hi @TimWilliams, The variable `rs!Price = 11`. The field `lblPU` value is ibtained by getting 5% off of  `rs!Price`. In this case, a whole number (11) is mulplied by a decimal (5%) and the result is correct with the decimal (10.45). But when the same type of calculation happens on the line below (`10.45*1`), then the resul is coming out without the decimal point. Sorry for the late reply, time difference

Comment: Hi @CetinBasoz, I haven't set any particular properties regarding the 1000s. I have read somewhere that VBA does use the `.` as a default decimal indicator so it should interpret it as such I guess. the thing, the first calculation is done with `5/100` and the output is `10.45`. So VBA itself is considering the `.`  as decimal. I don't know if it would change something to check for @computerVersteher's suggestion but I will try it out anyway

Comment: I didn't say you did something (actually you did indirectly). Check your computer's settings for decimal separator and such. In VBA and other languages 10.45 means 10 and 45/100, that is true. But here you are not using 10.45 as a literal but parsing a string (lblPU) to a numeric value. As a string "10.45" means 1045 if in your regional settings thousands separator is a dot and a decimal separator is a comma. Those settings are common in European windows installations for example. Please first check your regional settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing this in comments would be a mess. Instead of parsing a string to a decimal, directly use the decimal value:

```
Me.lblPU = (rs!price - (rs!price  * (5 / 100)))
Me.lblPriceTot = ((rs!price - (rs!price  * (5 / 100))) * CDec(Me.Qty))
```

Or:

```
dim price as decimal = (rs!price - (rs!price  * (5 / 100)))
Me.lblPU = price
Me.lblPriceTot = (price * CDec(Me.Qty))
```

Comment: Wow great! Thanks a lot Cetin! The first option worked fine

Answer (score 0):

If `Me.lblPU` is returning a string representation of the numerical value in which the decimal point is represented using a comma (perhaps due to regional settings), then `CDec` will return `1045` instead of `10.45`, observe:

```
?CDec("10.45")
 10.45 
?CDec("10,45")
 1045
```

I would suggest avoiding any potential string conversion and work with the numerical value directly, e.g.:

```
Me.lblPriceTot = 0.95 * rs!price * CDec(Me.Qty)
```

Similarly with the quantity field, use `rs!quantity` (if it exists).

Comment: can you provide a solution too? I know if he changes his formatting it will work, but I am curious to know how he can do that without doing mathematical manipulation etc?

Comment: Hi Lee, the thing is I don't have any control over the value of `lblPU`. It is a variable so I can't hardcode it in my program

Comment: @BrunoBukavuThai Cetin's answer is essentially the same as mine.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is very confusing that fields are named as labels.

Then, use a *variable* to cut it short:

```
Dim TruePrice As Currency

TruePrice = price * (1 - 5 / 100)
Me!lblPU.Value = TruePrice
Me!lblPriceTot.Value = TruePrice * Me!Qty.Value
```